# Why does column alias not work in doctrine?

Tags: php, sql, doctrine

My script is like this:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create ()
  ->select('count(p.product_id) as num_a')              
  ->from ( 'ProductComments p' )
  ->groupBy('p.product_id')
  ->having('num_a =2 ');
```

And the generated sql is:

```
SELECT COUNT(i.product_id) AS i__0 FROM productcomments i GROUP BY i.product_id HAVING num_a=2
```

Thus I get an error when execute the sql.

I have two questions:

1. why is the alias of the table `'i'` instead of `'p'`?
2. why is the `'num_a'` in having clause not replaced with `'i__0'`,how to fixed it?

Thanks for your suggestion...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 1: why is the alias of the table 'i'
>   instead of 'p'?
>
> 2: why is the 'num_a'
>   in having clause not replaced with
>   'i__0',how to fixed it?

Both questions are simply answered: Doctrine uses it's own aliases for the query. You do no need to know these aliases since they will not affect you nor will you need to work with it.

Even though Doctrine names the alias `i__0` you can access the attribute with your custom alias, e.g. `$yourObject->num_a` will have the proper value, namely the result of `count(p.product_id)`.

To see the output of your query is a useful debug feature, but relying on in inside your application is non-sense since these values are only used for the internal mechanisms of Doctrine.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. I completely agree with you that it's not necessary to know the generated alias. What puzzles me is that since the alias for count(p.product_id) is i__0, i__0 should be used in having clause instead of "num_a".

Comment: I recognise this was an old post, but I stumbled across it today and wanted to point out there are cases where this internal table alias mapping gets in the way - if you ever use a SQL function such as Within(), you can't use Doctrine aliases inside the function's params.

Answer (score 11):

I also had a problem with setting alias.
I had to set alias and then use "ORDER BY" with that alias.
Following solution worked for me:

```
$myQuery->addSelect('(<my select>) AS my_alias');
$myQuery->orderBy('my_alias');
```

In the result query looked like "...() AS p_0 ... ORDER BY p_0".
I hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

This would not be valid SQL.

SQL standard state that SELECT will be logically executed **after** `having`. So You need to repeat aliased code in `having`.

Good advice. As long as You work with SQL consuming DBs stick as closely to SQL as possible.