# Symfony 1.4 - How to recover the result of a count request in template?

Tags: php, count, request, symfony-1.4, recover

I have a problem.

**This is my request in my model  :**

```
public function nbDomainesParUrl($clientId)
{
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->from('domaine d')
        ->select('count(*)')
        ->where('d.client_id = ?', $clientId)
         ->leftJoin('d.Client c')
        ->leftJoin('d.CompteRegistar')
        ->groupBy('d.url')
    ;

    return $q;
}

public function executeGetDomainesParUrl($clientId)
{
    return $this->getDomainesParUrl($clientId)->execute();
}
```

**I execute this in my action.class.php like this :**

```
$this->nb_domaines = Doctrine::getTable('Domaine')->executeGetDomainesParUrl($request->getParameter('id'));
```

The result of this request is like this : 19,1,1

**But I don't know how to recover this result in my template.**

Answer (score 3):

You have to alias the count in order to retrieve it easily.

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
->from('domaine d')
->select('count(*) as nb')
[...]
```

And else in the result

if you use `->getResult()` :

```
$count = $result[0]['nb'];
```

With `$row = $query->execute()`

```
$count = $row['nb'];
```

Comment: It's also a good idea to run `execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY)` as this will return just a simple array and not a whole Doctrine object which is not needed in this case.

Comment: +1 [Michal Trojanowski](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1712294/michal-trojanowski) `execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY)` will limit memory impact! I'll update my answer...

Comment: Tkanks but when i alias the count it doesn't work because in the debug bar i see this request : 
SELECT COUNT(*) AS d__0 FROM domaine d LEFT JOIN client c ON d.client_id = c.id LEFT JOIN compte_registar c2 ON d.compte_registar_id = c2.id WHERE (d.client_id = '17') GROUP BY d.url

It puts as d__0 and not as nb and i don't know why.

Comment: In fact, it will work even... See [S.O topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675703/why-does-column-alias-not-work-in-doctrine)

Comment: Thank you JoDev and Michal Trojanowski

Comment: @PANPELOPE when Doctrine translates DQL into SQL queries it uses its' own aliases. But when the results are hydrated into objects or arrays your aliases defined in DQL are used. That's why you will see different aliases in the generated queries, but in code you should still use the ones you defined.

Comment: Ok Michal, thank you :) I use $this->nb_domaines = $query->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY); to genrate my array. But in my foreach only the first result is displayed. Why ?

Comment: `<?php foreach ($nb_domaines as $nb): ?>
        <?php  echo $nb['nb'];?>
      <?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: You can use [`->fetchAll()`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html) instead of `execute`...

Comment: You can test to loop using a `foreach` on the `fetchAll` result to build your array...

Comment: It's good I have used `Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_NONE` and it works :) Tkank you :)